# How to hide a table column in ASP MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following table view

[image]

I want to hide that red squared area form that table . Since I'm using this data in further actions I want to hide not remove it. The markup for the table is:

```
<table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Property_ID</th>
                    <th>IsChecked</th>
                    <th>Property Tile</th>
                    <th>Property Value</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="table"></tbody>
        </table>


        <table id="template" class="table" style="display: none;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span></span>
                    <input type="hidden" name="[#].Property_ID" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="[#].IsChecked" value="true" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="[#].IsChecked" value="false" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span></span>
                    <input type="hidden" name="[#].Property_Title" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span></span>
                    <input type="hidden" name="[#].Property_Value" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

this is javascript snippet to fill data to that table columns

```
  <script type="text/javascript">   

                var type = $('#Type');
                var category = $('#Category');
                var country = $('#Country');
                var product = $('#Product');
                var table = $('#table');

                $('#search').click(function () {

                    var url = '@Url.Action("FetchProductProperties")';
                    table.empty();
                    $.getJSON(url, { type: type.val(), category: category.val(), country: country.val(), product: product.val() }, function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                            var clone = $('#template').clone();
                            clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/\[#\]/g, '[' + index + ']'));
                            var cells = clone.find('td');
                            cells.eq(0).children('span').text(item.ID);
                            cells.eq(0).children('input').val(item.ID);
                            cells.eq(1).children('input').first().prop('checked', item.CheckOrNot)
                            cells.eq(2).children('span').text(item.Name);
                            cells.eq(2).children('input').val(item.Name);
                            cells.eq(3).children('span').text(item.PropertyValue);
                            cells.eq(3).children('input').val(item.PropertyValue);
                            $('#table').append(clone.find('tr'));
                        });
                    });
                });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to hide the column dynamically via javascript then add a class to that `<td>` element:

```
<table id="template" class="table" style="display: none;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span></span>
                <input type="hidden" name="[#].Property_ID" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="[#].IsChecked" value="true" />
                <input type="hidden" name="[#].IsChecked" value="false" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <span></span>
                <input type="hidden" name="[#].Property_Title" />
            </td>
            <td class="columnToHide">
                <span></span>
                <input type="hidden" name="[#].Property_Value" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Then you can call `$('.columnToHide').hide();` from javascript after you have populated the search results:

```
 $('#search').click(function () {

                var url = '@Url.Action("FetchProductProperties")';
                table.empty();
                $.getJSON(url, { type: type.val(), category: category.val(), country: country.val(), product: product.val() }, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        var clone = $('#template').clone();
                        clone.html($(clone).html().replace(/\[#\]/g, '[' + index + ']'));
                        var cells = clone.find('td');
                        cells.eq(0).children('span').text(item.ID);
                        cells.eq(0).children('input').val(item.ID);
                        cells.eq(1).children('input').first().prop('checked', item.CheckOrNot)
                        cells.eq(2).children('span').text(item.Name);
                        cells.eq(2).children('input').val(item.Name);
                        cells.eq(3).children('span').text(item.PropertyValue);
                        cells.eq(3).children('input').val(item.PropertyValue);
                        $('#table').append(clone.find('tr'));
                    });
                });

                $('.columnToHide').hide();
            });
```

At any point you can show the column by using `$('.columnToHide').show();` in your script.

Comment: does it hide ` <th>Property Value</th>` also ?

Comment: add the same class to the <th> element also if you want that hidden as well

Answer (score 1):

Are you using bootstrap? If yes, add class "hide" to the **th** and **td** tag that you want to hide.